# RedDot: Linking, referencing, lists and 'partial pages'

Tags: content-management-system, reddot

**UPDATED**

Using RedDot CMS, linking to a 'sub-page' (page within a page) directly will display JUST that sub-page, not within the context of its main parent. Referencing that sub-page WILL display it as I require.

I have a List linked to several pages via keywords. The template containing that list displays a link for each item. Clicking on any of these links results in a view of JUST the sub-page that is directly linked.

I require those links to display the sub-page within the context of its parent - e.g. the page on which its main link resides.

Let's say the base page has an ID of 100. It has a list containing sub-pages 201, 301, and 401. Respectively, each sub-pages' main link is 200, 300, and 400. When I view 100, I see that base page with a series of links to each page. However, clicking on any of those links displays page 201, 301, or 401. I require those links to point to pages 200, 300, and 400.

I cannot use target containers because each sub-page has a different parent.

Comment: I find this question a bit confusing. Can you an example of what you're trying to achieve or rephrase it somehow? 
Also a bit more details with samples of your code(specifically how you link pages/sub-pages) would make it easier to understand too.

Comment: @xelurg Are you familiar with RedDot CMS? If so, I would have thought that description was perfectly understandable, although I'll try a rewrite. If not, you have NO chance of helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just replicated the same thing on Reddot and have had a bit of a think about this, Is what you're after actually possible. As I understand it you're linking to the sub-page because that is where the keywords are assigned, but that sub-page could be contained in one ore more parent page.

If on your site the sub-page and the parent page are always one-to-one related then why have a sub-page at all. If the same sub-page is used in more than one parent would you want all the parent pages to be linked in your list?

UPDATE:

One idea, which is a bit of a hack is that you add an anchor to each sub-page that you then link to the preferred parent page, then instead of displaying the list normally you loop through the list using the render tags and display a link to the page in the anchor and not the subpage.

Comment: Well, I've ended up restructuring things completely, partly along the lines you suggest. Instead of linking to sub-pages (which contain the actual data I'm after and are therefore more appropriate), I'm linking to their parent pages. This puts a dependency on that parent/child structure remaining as is, but I think limitations of RedDot require that.